# how to simulate a stable & unstable manifold of a dynamical system in python?

Tags: python, mapping, differential-equations

I am trying to numerically calculate the stable & unstable manifold of a discrete dynamical system around the origin in python:

```
$x_{n+1} = x_{n} + y_{n} + \epsilon*sin(2*\pi*x_{n})$
$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \epsilon*sin(2*\pi*x_{n}) $
```

but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath
import math


x_val = []
y_val = []


run_x_val = []
run_y_val = []

x_range = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)
y_range = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)

t_range = np.linspace(0,5000)

epsilon = -0.5

for x in x_range:
    for y in y_range: #initial conditions
        init_x = x
        init_y = y
        x_run = x
        y_run = y
        for t in t_range:
            temp_y = y_run
            temp_x = x_run
            y_run += epsilon*math.sin(2*math.pi*temp_x)
            x_run += temp_y + epsilon*math.sin(2*math.pi*temp_x)
            print(x_run)
            print(y_run)
            run_x_val.append(x_run)
            run_y_val.append(y_run)
        if x_run == 0 and y_run == 0:
            x_val.append(init_x)
            y_val.append(init_y)


plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_val, y_val);

plt.figure()
plt.plot(run_x_val, run_y_val);


plt.show()
```

In my code the x and y values never seem to reach the origin, so when I try to plot it the resulting plot is just blank. Could someone point out the mistake I'm making?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten some parameters in your code:

```
x_run += temp_x + temp_y + epsilon*math.sin(2*math.pi*temp_x)
y_run += temp_y + epsilon*math.sin(2*math.pi*temp_x)
```

Secondly, none of your simulations end up at exactly the origin. The simulation that results in the end point being closest to the origin is at a starting point of.

`(-0.0050505050505050275, -0.0050505050505050275)`

You can keep track of this by replacing:

```
        if x_run == 0 and y_run == 0:
            x_val.append(init_x)
            y_val.append(init_y)
```

with

```
        last_point_distance_from_origin_sq = x_run**2 + y_run**2
        if last_point_distance_from_origin_sq < min_distance:
            min_distance = last_point_distance_from_origin_sq
            closest_run = (init_x, init_y)
```

This could of been a fluke however, if you continued to the next timestep perhaps that point had a high velocity, so it would be in a completely different location.

There can be a lot of reasons why it may not be at exactly the origin, if you are expecing some of the results to be so.

The most likely candidates are:

1. Numerical error, your timestamp could be too large so you get numerical instability.
2. Floating point error

Comment: The first point is not a point. Compare incremental add-to to assigning a sum. /// The question is not "what points close to the origin are reachable by the iteration", but "what initial points give iteration sequences that come close to the origin".